# click on home key and application run in background

Tags: android

I am trying to put code for if the home button is pressed then application process running in background.how implement code for my application run in background using codding in my application.here code but its not working when click on **home key**

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ||
            keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        this.moveTaskToBack(true);               
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here, when Home button is pressed or Your app is going to left.

```
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
                if (!taskInfo.isEmpty()) {
                  ComponentName topActivity = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity; 
                  if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {

                    Toast.makeText(xYourClassNamex.this, "YOU LEFT YOUR APP. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
                }
      }
```

Comment: when click on home key application get error but above code is working in background..