# Android clear ALWAYS the Back Stack

Tags: android, back-stack

There are many question here about this topic, but none of the answers works for me. I am programming an app that will carry sensitive data, and for such reason I want to make the user login each time it enters the app. I already tried the singletask launch mode and clearTaskOnLaunch, also I hide the task from the "Recents Apps" with the exclude from recents attribute.

But now the app don't behaves as it should with the Back button.

Example:

LoginActivity > MainActivity > HelpActivity

Now the user presses the *Home Button*, since the app is not on the recents list the user will need to use the launcher icon. LoginActivity pops up as expected but, if the user presses the *Back Button* it goes to Helpactivity instead of exitingn the app.

**Edit:** I already found the solution, the problem was that I was calling `finish()` on the `LoginActivity` after starting `MainActivity`. So when clicking on the launcher the Android system was re-parenting the Activities putting the new instantiated `LoginActivity` at the top of the stack, instead of clearing it leaving only the root Activity since there was not such Activity.

Comment: post your manifest please

Answer (score 0):

```
Have you tried noHistory option in manifest?
Also you can implement this by the use of SharedPreferences:
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
                if (!taskInfo.isEmpty()) {
                  ComponentName topActivity = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity; 
                  if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {

                    Toast.makeText(xYourClassNamex.this, "YOU LEFT YOUR APP. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//Here you can maintain a boolean value in sharedpreferences stating everytime you leave and login into the app. 


                  }
                }
      }
```

Here is the link : [click on home key and application run in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155844/click-on-home-key-and-application-run-in-background)

Comment: Ok, with that I can know whether the user leaves my app, this would be the appropriate timing to clearing the stack, but how to do it? On higher APIs I could use `finishAffinity()`, But my minSdk is 8. Why I would want to store a boolean value in the sharedprefs? I don't get it

Comment: Whenever and from any of the activity if you leave your app pressing home button at that time you can set that value to true and later by checking that flag you can decide whether to login again or not.