# Horizontal Scrollview containing a LinearLayout with a Listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-scrollview

I have LinearLayout which hierarchy looks like this: `HorizontalScrollview` as root, it contains a vertical `LinearLayout` and inside of it a horizontal `LinearLayout` as the header (made with `TextViews`) and a `ListView` just below.

Basically, the idea is to provide an horizontal scroll (since the ListView already has its vertical scroll). I almost got it, the problem is that the ListView don't expand its width enough to fit the content.

Here is the code of the Layout:

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/hscrollMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/fecha"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFechaDet"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tipo"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTipoEvtDet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/descripcion"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbEventListing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvEventos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I'm using a custom ArrayAdapter with a custom layout for the list item, the code is below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFechaEvtItem"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/fecha" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivEstadoEvtItem"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/estado"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_warning" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTipoEvtItem"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/tipo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescEvtItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/descripcion" />

</LinearLayout>
```

PD: Yeah I succesfully formatted the code with the SO editor, the [last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24864524) I messed it up xD.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you have set the first LinearLayout width to be wrap content. Try changing it to match_parent

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/hscrollMain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ...
```

Comment: Eclipse says: "ScrollView children must set their layout_width or layout_height attributes to wrap_content rather than fill_parent or match_parent in the scrolling dimension" So that's not an option, any other suggestion? Maybe I could put a widht in DP to the ListView, I'm gonna try it.

Comment: If that doesn't work try to change layout width for horizontal scrollview to be hardcoded values or fill_parent

Comment: Yeah, I hardcoded the width of the `ListView`, it's not the best option but it's the best that I have. In any case there is a `DetailActivity` which displays the information of a specific item, so in case the info don't fit in the `ListView` the user can see it by going to the details of that item.